# Angular2 + Chart.js and ng2-charts. Data binding not working as expected

Tags: javascript, charts, angular, chart.js

I'm trying to implement `Chart.js` into my `Angular2` application. I'm using [ng2-charts](http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) directives, too. I set everything as shown in the examples and when I run the app with the sample data everything is ok. The problem comes when I try with my own data. The actual problem is that I'm using a service to load the data within a `ngOnInit()` method and this way the chart directive is initialized before I have the data (or I guess so). I'm getting this not very descriptive error:

> "EXCEPTION: TypeError: t is undefined in [barChartOptions in trafficComponent@6:16]"

It doesn't really say much :) The problem is not in the `barChartOptions` because I'm replacing only the `barChartLabels` and `barChartData` parameters, the rest parameters are as in the example. My parameters are also correct and valid and they are not the problem, too.
I'm wondering if there is a way for reloading (re-initializing) the directive with some `Promise`-like solution or taking advantage of the lifecycle hooks.
I'll be **VERY** glad if there is anyone else who has ever faced the same problem and is ready to share his solution :)

### **Update**

I logged in the console the `data` object passed to the `Chart` constructor as `new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, options);` and the `labels` and `datasets.data` properties are *undefined* although I logged them one more time right after I got the data from the service and there they were correct. I think that some kind of data binding should do the trick but I don't know how to achieve it in this case. Actually there is a data binding (as shown in the examples in [ng2-charts](http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/)) but it doesn't work as I expect. Changing properties in my component doesn't affect the properties of the `Charts` directive and they remain *undefined*.

### **Update 2 (2016-02-19)**

After updating to the newly released Angular version `2.0.0-beta.7` everything is working as expected.

Comment: I have tried to add chart js to my app the error is p-chart isn't known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Angular 2.0.0-beta.7 solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with using chart.js when trying to create a line graph. All my data was showing as undefined. Not sure if your issue is the exact same as mine, but I can at least point you in the direction of my solution which was to use the Dynamic Component Loader.

[Chart.js not showing in Angular2 if it doesn't exist on the main page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322638/chart-js-not-showing-in-angular2-if-it-doesnt-exist-on-the-main-page/35324579#35324579)

Comment: Yeah, thank you for sharing your solution. It seems to work except that loading the component that holds the canvas element (in your case CanvasComponent) with `DynamicComponentLoader` doesn't call its `ngOnInit` hook which I need for calling my service that provides me the data.

Comment: `Interpolation` and Angular2's core directives like `*ngIf` don't seem to work in the loaded with `DynamicComponentLoader` component, too. I don't know if it is a bug or something specific that is missing in the documentation yet.