# Chart is not working in Angular2

Tags: charts, typescript, angular, bar-chart

I am trying to create Bar Chart using this [github repo](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/tree/1f2326f8af5ffcef6d5277606c1ff30fe273c14c). But my chrome does not display chart. 
Here is my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vfsert1sAJ4dsVR4MdyV?p=preview). I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Here is my updated code:

app.ts

```
import {Component, Pipe, PipeTransform} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, FORM_DIRECTIVES, Control, ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';
import {CHART_DIRECTIVES} from './ng2-charts.ts'; 

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html',
    directives: [CHART_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent { 
  constructor() {
    console.log('bar demo');
  }

  private barChartOptions = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true,
    multiTooltipTemplate: '<%if (datasetLabel){%><%=datasetLabel %>: <%}%><%= value %>'
  };
  private barChartLabels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
  private barChartSeries = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
  public barChartType = 'Bar';
  private barChartLegend:boolean = true;

  private barChartData = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  ];

  // events
  chartClicked(e:any) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  chartHovered(e:any) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

app.html

```
<base-chart class="chart"
           [data]="barChartData"
           [labels]="barChartLabels"
           [options]="barChartOptions"
           [series]="barChartSeries"
           [legend]="barChartLegend"
           [chartType]="barChartType"
           (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
           (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></base-chart>
```

Suggest me if there is any  another library for displaying data on the bar chart for angular2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this question could help you:

- [Chart.js not showing in Angular2 if it doesn't exist on the main page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322638/chart-js-not-showing-in-angular2-if-it-doesnt-exist-on-the-main-page/35324579#35324579)

Comment: your suggested github repo is same with question's repo, is't it ?

Comment: Oh, you're right. It's because I only see `Chart.js` included in the plunkr (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js)... The TypeScript file from ng2-charts is copied into the plunkr. That's why I thought, it wasn't ng2-charts. Thanks very much for pointing this out!

Answer (score 5):

Eleboration of @Thierry's answer with example.

updated code is here:

app.ts

```
import {Component, DynamicComponentLoader, Injector} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, FORM_DIRECTIVES, Control, ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';
import {ChartDirective} from './charts.ts';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html',
    directives: [ChartDirective, NgClass, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent { 

 constructor() {

    }

}
```

app.html

```
<div class="container details-container">
  <topics></topics>
</div>

<div class="graph-container">
    <div class="row no-pad" style="position: relative;">
        <div style="margin-left:14px; z-index: 100; height: 250px;">    
            <canvas id="myChart" chart height="250" width="350"></canvas>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

chart.ts

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Input} from 'angular2/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[chart]'
})
export class ChartDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
        //el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        var data = {
          labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
          datasets: [
              {
                  label: "My First dataset",
                  fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                  strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                  highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                  highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                  data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
              },
              {
                  label: "My Second dataset",
                  fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                  strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
                  highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
                  highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                  data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
              }
          ]
      };

        var options = {
            scaleBeginAtZero : true,scaleShowGridLines : true,
            scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
            scaleGridLineWidth : 1,
            scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
            scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
            barShowStroke : true,
            barStrokeWidth : 2,
            barValueSpacing : 5,
            barDatasetSpacing : 1,
            legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"

          }

        var ctx: any = el.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
        var BarChart = new Chart(ctx);
        BarChart.Bar(data, options);             

    }

}
```

working plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Vfsert1sAJ4dsVR4MdyV?p=preview