# highcharts for Angular 2 - No Directive annotation found on ChartComponent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts, angular

I'm trying to get highcharts for Angular 2 to work with my project. However, when I add the `CHART_DIRECTIVES` to my `directives` array in `@Component`, I get the error in my browser console:

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): No Directive annotation found on ChartComponent

Does anyone know what this means and how to go about fixing this??

**EDIT:**
I'm trying to incorporate this chart package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts.                                     I added CHART_DIRECTIVES by following the instructions on that site with:

```
import {Http, Headers, Response, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {Component, Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Routes} from '../routes.config';

import { CHART_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2-highcharts';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './app/home/home.html',
    directives: [CHART_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS
    ]
})
```

Comment: What Angular2 version? Can you show some code?

Comment: have you add this import line in your file `import {CHART_DIRECTIVES} from './ng2-charts.ts';` ?

Comment: See edit in original post.

Comment: seems your chart package is expired .

Comment: Are you saying the 'highcharts' package is obsolete? I'm completely new to Angular 2. Is there a way to update it via npm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issues. I was able to resolve it by upgrading my application to use the latest RC version of angular2.

> The latest release 0.1.0 of **angular2-highcharts** is now upgraded to
>   the **rc.1** (RC version).

I think it's a compatibility issue here even though you import the ***Component*** annotation is imported from angular library, it fails to identify it. You are trying to use an older *angular2* version while the angular2-highcharts that we use is based on the latest release of angular2 which has a lot of breaking changes.

Change Log: 
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

```
/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />

import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CHART_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2-highcharts';

@Component({
    selector: 'simple-chart',
    directives: [CHART_DIRECTIVES],
    templateUrl: 'templates/simple_chart.html'
})
export class SimpleChart {
    constructor() {
        this.options = {
            title : { text : 'simple chart' },
            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
            }]
        };
    }
    options: Object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your use case it seems you havn't add `import {CHART_DIRECTIVES} from './ng2-charts.ts';`
this line while imorting chart in your .ts file.

Apart from this if you are going to use charts in angular2 you can Refer here

- [Chart.js not showing in Angular2 if it doesn't exist on the main page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35322638/5043867)
- [Chart is not working in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35571260/5043867)

<kbd>[Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vfsert1sAJ4dsVR4MdyV?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: I'm trying to incorporate this chart package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts.

Comment: could you recreate your problem on plunker ?