# Ng2-charts app not showing charts

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng2-charts

I followed the instructions on the ng2-charts demo page to get set up.  I'm using angular-cli so I also imported the packages using System.JS.  Then I copied the demo code, but it won't display. The canvas is being created but no chart is being drawn. My component and template code are exactly the same as [here](http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849490/ng2-chart-doesnt-display-as-expected-even-more-the-console-doesnt-show-any-err?rq=1

Comment: do you have a solution I have added ng2 charts : Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'base-chart'.

Answer (score 11):

Use `<div style="display: block">` around `canvas` tag

Your final html code should look similar to this

```
<div style="display: block">
  <canvas
    baseChart
    [chartType]="'line'"
    [datasets]="chartData"
    [labels]="chartLabels"
    [options]="chartOptions"
    [legend]="true"
    (chartClick)="onChartClick($event)">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked. I has almost pulled my hairs on this.

Answer (score 6):

`responsive: true` sometimes the problem. When changed to false the will canvas appear.

Comment: you saved me some time man, never thought this would cause my issue. Thanks a lot! Do you know if theirs another way to fix this, while keeping responsive true?

Answer (score 1):

In case, you're fetching data from API, try this

```
@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart?: BaseChartDirective;

getChartData(){
  // do something
  this.chart?.chart?.update()
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Adding for future seekers

In my case, it was the chart type. I was using `horizontalbar`. It worked when i changed it to `bar` or `horizontalBar`.